# Syntax error in Microsoft Excel macro for converting into PDF

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub invoicepdf()
Sheet2.Range("a1:j53").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePdf,Filename:="C:\Invoice data\" & Sheet2.Range("j12").Value, OpenAfterPublish:=true
End Sub
```

I'm using this in Excel vb for converting Excel to PDF, but I'm seeing syntax error.

Can somebody please help where am doing the mistake.

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: The way you are selecting two data ranges is wrong, check my Answer, help you to work with multiple data ranges to convert to PDF. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Sheet2 with Worksheets("Sheet2") in your vb script:

```
Sub invoicepdf()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:j53").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePdf,Filename:="C:\Invoice data\" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("j12").Value, OpenAfterPublish:=true
End Sub
```

Also check that there is no destination file with the name you have specified in cell J12 otherwise your script will fail

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this Macro to export/convert multiple data ranges to PDF file.**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

 Range("A82:D90,A92:E93,A96:C98").Select
 Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 "C:\temp\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
  True

End Sub
```

**Note,**

1. *Adjust the cell references as needed.*
2. *File path & Name are editable.*

Comment: So why don't you provide an answer that is tailored to the question?

Comment: @DavidPostill,  thanks for raising a good point ,, could you plz help me where I did wrong, so that I can edit the post. Since I've written to OP that the method to use 2 Ranges is wrong in comments above and suggest the OP full length VBA code to finish the job. ☺